# How do I partition a list into (sub-)lists of random length?

Tags: list, emacs

Input, by example (`4` is the maximum length):

```
(my-partition-randomly '(a b c d e f g h i j k l) 4)
```

Output:

```
'((a b c) (d) (e f g h) (i j k) (l))
```

The code should run in the Emacs Lisp interpreter.

Comment: Can you show the code for your current attempt to write it?

Comment: @AlexOtt No attempt yet. I could write something rather complex, but am looking for a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My elisp-fu is weak, but I was able to write the following function:

```
(defun my-partition-randomly (list max-length) ""
       (let ((result '()))
         (while list
           (push (seq-take-while (lambda (x) x)
                                 (map 'list
                                      (lambda (x) (pop list))
                                      (number-sequence 1 (+ 1 (random max-length)))))
                 result))
         (reverse result)))
```

It extracts random initial sequences of the input list and adds them to result (the `seq-take-while` is needed not to include `nil`s when the last subsequence wants to be longer than the remaining list). `push` adds elements to the left, so the result has to reversed.

Comment: Thanks, your elisp-fu is better than mine, and this does the trick! I learned new functions, `seq-take-while` and `map`, and this was kind of the intention of my question. Let’s see if there is an even simpler solution.

Comment: You might get more attention at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/ with your future questions.

Comment: I chose Stack Overflow because my question is about Elisp the programming language. (not a fan of having so many overlapping platforms now)